# Getting count of number of elements in mongodb when documents are less than $limit (aggregation)

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I cold not find anywhere that what happens when we limit the number of elements to `N` and the actual documents prsent according to filter are `k` where `k>N`. My common sense says that developers have take care of the this via `minimum (N,actual_found)` but I could not find a solution.

I have a query in `pymongo` where I want to find the number of documents according to the filter.
I have a query something like that:

```
query = [{"$match": {"$expr": {"$and": [{"$lte": [{"$strLenCP": {"$ifNull": ["$eng_text",""]}},0]},
                                        {"$lte": [{"$strLenCP": {"$ifNull": ["$hindi_text",""]}},0]},
                                        {"$lte": [{"$strLenCP": {"$ifNull": ["$latex",""]}},0]}]}}},
         {"$limit": 1000000}]

objs =  db.questions.aggregate(query)
```

The problem is that when I ran

```
count=0
for obj in objs:
    count+=1
print(count)
>>>
320953
```

It gave me the results but a lot of time was taken as it had to go to server to fetch every query and then a loop.

Is there any method where I can find the count of results?

I tried `db.questions.count_documents(query)` and `db.documents.count_documents({query})`
and it returned me an error. MAybe because these are aggregating thing or for whatever reason. I am not a DB guy but just want to see a logic to get the data. I think I can reshape the query and then use `count_documents()`. Could someone please tell me a way to do that?

Comment: There is a  $count operator.

Comment: Count is a method in `pymongo` which is replaced by `count_documents()` in current version. Could you please tell how can I use that `count` in my  case?

Comment: try: `objs =  list(db.questions.aggregate(query)) and then print(len(objs))`

Comment: The problem with that query is it is using aggregation operators like `$strLenCP`.  These can only be used in a query inside an [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) expression.

Comment: SO you mean to say I can use it directly? I'll have to use `list(generator)`?